# Kentico - Change text content based on querystring value

Tags: kentico

I have one Contact us page with an intro blurb saying something like: ***Let us know how [we] can help you***. The text inside the brackets needs to change based on the query string value.

For example:

If the URL is mysite.com/contact?p=product -> the text inside the
   brackets is:  [our technical sales rep]

If the URL is
   mysite.com/contact?p=sf -> [our consultants in San Francisco office]

...

I can grab the query string value, but don't know how to use it with multiple ifs in the example above? Could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Let us know how
    {% 
    param = QueryString.p.ToLower().TrimEnd().TrimStart();
    result = "we"; // default value
    if(param == "product") {result ="our technical sales rep"}
    if(param == "sf") {result = "our consultants in San Francisco office"}
    if(param == "bla") {result = "bla bla bla"}
    return result;
    #%} can help you
```

Answer (score 1):

For this your best bet is to create a [custom macro method](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/macro-expressions/extending-the-macro-engine/registering-custom-macro-methods) which will allow you to write a more robust logical statement and simply pass in the query string as the value.

The simplest approach is to pass along the actual string you want displayed in the URL as an encoded string and simply decode is when you get the value using a macro.

Your string text might look something like:

`Let us know how {% QueryString.GetValue("p")|(default)"we" %} can help you.`

Comment: Thank you! That's what I did but some urls became too long and a bit too overwhelming.

Comment: Agree that a custom macro method would be a cleaner solution.